# Fractal signal analysis

Tags: real-analysis, book-recommendation, fractals, fractal-analysis

What kind of results can be proven about continuous functions $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ which present some sort of **fractal** behaviour / self-similarity?

Do you have some textbook recommendation about fractal signal analysis?

Comment: you probably want continuos , nowhere differentiable functions.

Comment: @Ant yes exactly, you're right. I added "continuous" in the question.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is quite broad, but you might want to have a look at:

- [Kenneth Falconer "Fractal Geometry: Mathematical Foundations and Applications, Second Edition"](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/book/10.1002/0470013850) (a classic)
- [Jorgensen, Palle E. T. "Analysis and Probability, Wavelets, Signals, Fractals"](http://www.springer.com/en/book/9780387295190) (more along the lines you seem to request)

Comment: Thanks! What kind of "classical" problems can be proven  such continuous functions with fractal behaviour?

Comment: You are welcome :) Fractal geometry and analysis on fractals are whole fields of mathematics! Don't take me wrong, but you cannot expect to receive any useful answer to such a broad question (or I can't give it, especially since I'm no expert). I suggest you have a look at those books and then you post a more precise question.

Comment: Of course, yes, they are broad fields of maths. But, to make a comparison with analytic number theory (which is a whole field too) which I know a bit more about, one could easily give a "big picture" of the famous open (or solved) problems : prime number theorem (proved ~ 1899), conjecture: Riemann hypothesis, twin prime conjecture & related sieve problems, etc.
Could someone give the big picture of problems (and theorems) about analysis of continuous functions that have fractal behaviour?